# Paid version of SO without ads?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, advertising, user-experience

One of my favorite things about SO is the easily-scannable layout, a masterpiece of tech Q&A design.

The layout is marred by ads.

Will there be a paid version without ads?

Sorry if this has been asked -- I searched but couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: If you have enoguh reputation, you see just one ad in the whole page, in the sidebar.

Comment: Precisely -- you just need two more upvotes, and they're gone.

Comment: So yes, paid for in contributions worth upvoting.  ;)

Comment: Or, for the low, low price of US$50, I'll award you a +200 rep bounty, which will practically guarantee you a reduced-ad experience for the rest of your time on Stack Overflow! Act now, and it'll also be worth +100 rep on every other Stack Exchange site. Please remit payment to: Legitimate Business, 123 Fake Street, Springfield, USA.

Comment: I'll do it for U$S 40

Comment: Fantastic!  SO: also a masterpiece of tech Q&A game-mechanics design.  (I suppose that mostly renders my question moot, unless anyone cares to chime in.)  Thanks for the responses, especially with the personalized research, @balpha.

Comment: I'll do it for $100. My points are worth more than Pop and Juan's.

Comment: @PD and @Juan -- nice ;)  It's tempting.

Comment: BTW - you have > 200 rep. you're welcome.

Comment: It's $10 for 2 upvotes -- on sale.

Comment: Not unless *someone* downvotes him 3 times @Jon, he should pay "protection money" now

Comment: @Juan - Gee, I sure hope no one flags a bunch of your posts as offensive. That would be a real shame.

Comment: It should be mentioned that not all of the adds go away.  There is still 1 (or 2) side adds left.

Comment: @Jon (and I suspect other anonymous angel(s)) -- I'll do my best to play the part.  Thanks!!  @Juan I knew I'd only be able to avoid the SO Mafia for so long...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the https://stackoverflow.com/faq

> Amass enough reputation points and Stack Overflow will allow you to go beyond simply asking and answering questions:
>
> **200** - Reduced advertising

Answer (score 0):

Just install adblock and recommended filters. That'll get rid of all ads on SO except the self-promotion ads, which can be quite annoying.

Comment: I'd rather keep the add supported websites around.  Nothing good in this (technology) world is free. (Save very few exceptions)

Comment: that's nice of you, but people in general don't want to waste their attention.